# Putting element at the position where user clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a div that looks like a virtual text area, when user clicks it, my code creates a input element without border and outline so that the user feels he is typing in a textarea. On that input element, I give them autocomplete and when user selects an option, element gets added to the text area. Virtually it feels like user is typing in the textarea itself.

However, I also want to enable users to go back and forth in the textarea so that they can edit or remove elements that they added earlier. On press of arrow keys, I can shift the input box before or after elements. But I also want to enable users to click anywhere in the text area and put the input element there so that user can type there.

Bottom line, on click of the textarea, I want to detect before which element exactly user clicked. Thanks.

**Update :**
Here is a snapshot of the text area with some elements in it. 
[image: Custom textarea]

The code to create the input element is this :

```
$(".textarea").click(function(){
        if($(this).find(".placeholder").length>0) $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        if($(this).find(".element-input").length>0){
            $(this).find(".element-input").focus();
        }else{
            var input=$("<input class='element-input' name='element-input'/>");
            $(this).append(input);
            input.focus();
        }
    });
```

Each of the input element has a class `elm`. When a user click between 2 elements, I want to detect before which element the user has clicked.

Comment: some code can helps us help you ;)

Comment: Just a minute, I will add snapshots of text area and a code snippet.

Comment: What's wrong with your code then ?

Comment: read my question? Its a linear text box, you can only add element at the end or remove from the end. Like a stack. I want to enable users to get anywhere in the textarea and edit from that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to find the element before the clicked position, based on the mouseclick client x & y values. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baga143/5AXwH/)

```
    $(".textarea").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'txtEditor')
            return true;

        var elementBefore = null;
        $(".elm").each(function () {
            var startY = $(this).position().top;
            var endY = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
            if (e.clientY >= startY && e.clientY <= endY) {
                var startX = $(this).position().left;
                var endX = $(this).position().left + $(this).width();
                if (e.clientX >= startX && e.clientX <= endX) {
                    elementBefore = null;
                    return false; //do nothing if clicked within an elm
                }
                if (e.clientX > endX) {
                    if (!elementBefore)
                        elementBefore = this;
                    else if ((e.clientX - $(this).position().left)
                     < (e.clientX - $(elementBefore).position().left)) {
                        elementBefore = this;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if (elementBefore) {
            //if($(this).find(".placeholder").length>0) $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            if ($(this).find(".element-input").length <= 0) {
                var input = $("<input id='txtEditor' class='element-input' name='element-input'/>");
                $(this).append(input);
                input.focus();
            }
            $(this).find(".element-input").insertAfter($(elementBefore));
            $(this).find(".element-input").focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow. this seems to be working.. :D :D Thanks a lot. Let me first understand the code and then I will accept the answer. Thanks for the effort. :)